# How to manipulate an array generated from .reduce function into separate key/value pairs? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm struggling to resolve an issue I'm having with .reduce;

Currently, I am iterating through an array to count the number of duplicates as can be seen below;

```js
var data = ['141:150.5', '141:150.5', '141:150.5', '224:297.5','83:351.5','278:434.5','332:182', '332:182','263:135','256:155','256:155','105:65']


var reducer = function(tally, vote) {
  if(!tally[vote]){
    tally[vote] = 1
  } else {
    tally[vote] = tally[vote] + 1;
  }
  
  return tally;
}

var result = data.reduce(reducer, {});

console.log(result)
```

What I would like to do is split the output of each item from this array into an object which has 3 key/value pairs.

So taking the first result from the output above `("141:150.5": 3)` I would like to generate the following;

```
{ 
value1: 141,
value2: 150.5,
count: 3
},
```

and so on so forth.

However since the above function doesn't output an array length, it means I cannot iterate through `result` in order to start building the desired objects.

I'm a bit lost here - any help/advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can iterate over it using `for..in`. Just split key by `:` and create an object

Comment: _the above function doesn't output an array length.._ You have an **object** in result, not array, so you **cannot** get its length. Use `for..in` to iterate through an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, you just have to split the `key` value and process accordingly.

Also, I have taken leisure to update your reduce function.

```js
var data = ['141:150.5', '141:150.5', '141:150.5', '224:297.5', '83:351.5', '278:434.5', '332:182', '332:182', '263:135', '256:155', '256:155', '105:65']

var reducer = function(tally, vote) {
  tally[vote] = (tally[vote] || 0) + 1;
  return tally;
}

var result = data.reduce(reducer, {});

var output = [];
for(var k in result){
  var _t = k.split(":");
  output.push({
    value1: _t[0],
    value2: _t[1],
    count: result[k]
  });
}

console.log(output)
```

You can also update your reduce function to directly give output like:

```js
var data = ['141:150.5', '141:150.5', '141:150.5', '224:297.5', '83:351.5', '278:434.5', '332:182', '332:182', '263:135', '256:155', '256:155', '105:65']

var count = 1;
var reducer = function(p, c, i, a) {
  if (p && p !== c) {
    var _t = p.split(":");
    result.push({
      value1: _t[0],
      value2: _t[1],
      count: count
    });
    count = 1;
    if (i === a.length - 1) {
      _t = c.split(":");
      result.push({
        value1: _t[0],
        value2: _t[1],
        count: count
      });
    }
  } else {
    count++;
  }
  return c
}

var result = [];
data.sort().reduce(reducer);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate the object using for-in loop, and split the key by `:` using `.split(':')`:

```js
var data = ['141:150.5', '141:150.5', '141:150.5', '224:297.5', '83:351.5', '278:434.5', '332:182', '332:182', '263:135', '256:155', '256:155', '105:65']

var reducer = function(tally, vote) {
  if (!tally[vote]) {
    tally[vote] = 1
  } else {
    tally[vote] = tally[vote] + 1;
  }

  return tally;
}

var result = data.reduce(reducer, {});

for (const key in result) {
  const value = key.split(':')
  result[key] = {value1: value[0], value2: value[1], count: result[key]}
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were part way there.

```js
var data = ['141:150.5', '141:150.5', '141:150.5', '224:297.5', '83:351.5', '278:434.5', '332:182', '332:182', '263:135', '256:155', '256:155', '105:65']
var reducer = function (tally, vote) {
    if (!tally[vote]) {
        tally[vote] = 1
    } else {
        tally[vote] = tally[vote] + 1;
    }
    return tally;
}
var result = data.reduce(reducer, {});

var result2 = [];
for (key in result) {
    var a = {};
    a.value1 = Number(key.split(":")[0]);
    a.value2 = Number(key.split(":")[1]);
    a.count = result[key];
    result2.push(a);
}
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys( result ).length` will give you the number of keys

Answer (score 0):

```
var m = [];
_.forEach(result,function(value,key){
         let k = key.split(':');
         m.push({value1:parseInt(k[0]),value2:parseInt(k[1]),count:value});
});
console.log(m)
```

Here is the script for works exactly what you are looking for. It make use of Lodash. Have a great day !!!

Answer (score -1):

```
Just try the below code:


var data = ['141:150.5', '141:150.5', '141:150.5', '224:297.5', '83:351.5', '278:434.5', '332:182', '332:182', '263:135', '256:155', '256:155', '105:65']

var reducer = function(tally, vote) {
  if (!tally[vote]) {
    tally[vote] = 1
  } else {
    tally[vote] = tally[vote] + 1;
  }

  return tally;
}

var result = data.reduce(reducer, {});

console.log(result);
var resultArr = [];
for(var key in result) {
    var obj = {};
  var splitArr = key.split(":");
  obj.value1 = splitArr[0];
  obj.value2 = splitArr[1];
  obj.count = result[key];
  resultArr.push(obj);
}

console.log(resultArr);

Now if you want to access data you can try like this:
console.log(resultArr[0].value1);
console.log(resultArr[0].value2);
console.log(resultArr[0].count);
```

Answer (score -2):

If I don't misunderstand what you want to do, you can iterate your "result" object by using for in :

```
for (var prop in result) {
    if (result.hasOwnProperty(prop )) {
        var val = result[prop];
        // then output your desired format
    }
}
```